# Weekends in a Month in R

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to prepare an xreg serie for my Arima model and I will use number of weekends in a month for it. I can find results for a year but when it is longer than a year, it usually is, I couldn't find a way. 
 Here is what I do so far.

```
dates <- seq(from=as.Date("2001-01-01"), to=as.Date("2010-12-31"), by = "day")
wd <- weekdays(dates)
aylar <- months(dates[which(wd == "Sunday" | wd == "Satuday")])

table(aylar)
```

What I want is gathering all months' weekends not based on only months but also years. So that I can have the same length of serie with my original forecast serie.

Comment: you know the function `is.weekend()` from package `chron`?

Comment: Nope. I assume it returns true if it is weekend. But still how can I organize them based on year and month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
library(chron)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

month <- months(dates[chron::is.weekend(dates)])
day <- dates[chron::is.weekend(dates)]

# create data.frame
df <- data.frame(date = day, month = month, year = chron::years(day))

df %>% group_by(year, month) %>% summarize(weekends = floor(n()/2))

#   year    month weekends
#   <dbl>   <fctr>    <dbl>
#1   2001    April        4
#2   2001   August        4
#3   2001 Dezember        5
#4   2001  Februar        4
#5   2001   Januar        4
#6   2001     Juli        4
#7   2001     Juni        4
#8   2001      Mai        4
#9   2001     März        4
#10  2001 November        4
## ... with 110 more rows
```

I hope this is a starting point for your work.

Comment: I wish us Americans spelled it "Dezember".  That just looks cooler than December.

Comment: "Marz" is also cool I think. :) and year = years(day) I assume. It seems working. Thanks. :) Which language is this btw?

Comment: Error: could not find function "year". I made it years and it worked. In Turkey, almost all high schools has one year class for basic German but not mine. :)